# Count columns with multiple values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "col1": ["Kev", "Kev", "Fr"],
    "col2": ["Red; Purple", "Yellow; Purple; Red", "Red; Yellow"], }, index=["1", "2", "3"])
```

It'll look like this

```
    col1 col2
1   Kev  Red; Purple
2   Kev  Yellow; Purple; Red
3   Fr   Red; Yellow
```

I want to count all the items in col2 according to col1. In this case the final df will be like this:

```
    col1 col2   count
1   Kev  Red    2
2   Kev  Purple 2
3   Kev  Yellow 1
4   Fr   Red    1
5   Fr   Yellow 1
```

I tried using explode:

```
df2 = (df.explode(df.columns.tolist())
      .apply(lambda col: col.str.split(';'))
      .explode('col1')
      .explode('col2'))
```

but that only gives me col1 and col2 of my desired dataframe, not the count. If I use `crosstab` on df2, I'll get a very different result.

I managed to get the desired output with 2 nested for loops, but my dataframe is so big that it takes almost a minute loading the function. I want to avoid this solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After `pd.crosstab`, you can try `melt`

```py
df2 = (df.explode(df.columns.tolist())
      .apply(lambda col: col.str.split('; ')) # <-- space here
      .explode('col1')
      .explode('col2'))


out = (pd.crosstab(df2['col1'], df2['col2'])
       .melt(value_name='count', ignore_index=False)
       .reset_index())
```

```
print(out)

  col1    col2  count
0   Fr  Purple      0
1  Kev  Purple      2
2   Fr     Red      1
3  Kev     Red      2
4   Fr  Yellow      1
5  Kev  Yellow      1
```

Comment: Be aware that your solution add a new row "Fr:Purple:0" :)

Answer (score 2):

According to your example, you just need to explode `col2` after spliting the strings.

Here is a simpler way using [`DataFrame.value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.value_counts.html)

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "col1": ["Kev", "Kev", "Fr"],
    "col2": ["Red; Purple", "Yellow; Purple; Red", "Red; Yellow"], }, index=["1", "2", "3"])


df2 = (
    df.assign(col2=df['col2'].str.split('; '))
      .explode('col2')
      .value_counts()
      .rename('count')
      .reset_index()
)
```

Output:

```
>>> df2 

  col1    col2  count
0  Kev  Purple      2
1  Kev     Red      2
2   Fr     Red      1
3   Fr  Yellow      1
4  Kev  Yellow      1
```

Comment: If I was picky, I would add one more parameter to your code: ".sort_values(by='col1', ascending=False)" ;)

Comment: @Drakax `value_counts` already sorts by default in descending order ;)

Comment: Oh nevermid ... it sorts by frequency! I see that you mean by `col1`, sorry. I don't know if OP wants that, but I'm glad to add your suggestion if he does :)